# Can every function/equation in two dimensions can be generalized into an equivalent/similar function/equation in three dimensions?

Tags: functions, polynomials, graphing-functions

Like, say, $z=x^2+y^2$ looks like a generalized form of $z=x^2$ (& $z=y^2$) and the later can be derived by putting $y=0$ (& $z=0$). Also, graphically the later looks like a segment/slice of the former. Similar, is the case about the equation of sphere and equation of circle. What about the case of sine (&cosine) function?

Is there any list/theory where I can find such generalized functions?

Comment: The examples $z=x^2+y^2$ and the sphere are both surfaces of revolution around the $z$ axis. If that's the kind of "generalization" you want then only _even_ functions will remain functions in 3D. But it's not clear what you're really looking for.

Comment: @David I'm looking for the figures in 3D whose slice/layers represents the similar figures in 2D. It would be pretty here if both the figures are algebraically similar too.

Comment: Given a graph $z=f(x)$ in 2D, the graph $z=f(x+y)$ has the 2D slices $z=f(x)$ for $y=0$ and $z=f(y)$ for $x=0$. Applying this idea to $y=x^2$ gives us the function $z=x^2+2xy+y^2$.